# Estimation of Vandermonde matrix

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

<sub>Cross-posted on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326279/how-to-learn-a-vandermonde-matrix-from-data).</sub>

---

I would like to discuss how to tackle an optimization problem to learn a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). In particular, I have an optimization problem in the following form:

\begin{align}
V &= \operatorname{argmin}_{V}\|A -  \operatorname{diag}(Vb )C\|_F^2
\end{align}
where $A,C$ are $N \times N$ matrices, $V$ is a $N \times K$ Vandermonde matrix with $N >K$ and $b$ is a $K \times 1$ vector of coefficients.

This is a generalization of FIR filter design, where instead of finding the filter coefficients $b$ we search for the basis vectors $\{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$ of the Vandermonde matrix. Each of this vector is such that $v_{i+1}= v_i \odot v_1 $, i.e., it is a geometric progression over the rows.

How can I learn the matrix $V$? Is there a a way to rewrite such problem in a form easier to optimize?

The problem is not convex, since it is the composition of a norm with a non-affine mapping of the $N$ variables contained in $v_1$. Exploiting the relationship between Frobenius norm and trace property, I could arrive at the problem of minimizing $V$ over the function:

$$\operatorname{vec}(Z)^\top \operatorname{vec}(Z) -2 \operatorname{vec}(A)^{\top}\operatorname{vec}(Z) $$

where $\operatorname{vec}(Z)= \operatorname{vec}(C)^\top (I \odot I) \operatorname{vec}(Vb)$.
Might this help in solving for $V$? (or better, for $v_1$?).